# Receiving multiple sendto() from servers

Tags: visual-c++, winsock

My client is sending a UDP broadcast to all servers on the subnet. Each server will reply back to the client so that the client can obtain/store the servers ip address. Not every time will all the servers get the message (probably because of UDP?). Is the best way around this to increment a counter to broadcast when it finds a new ip address of a server?

The other issue is currently on the client side, it will get only 1 message at a time. Is it possible to receive multiple messages at the same time?

This is my client code:

```
    if (recvfrom(Socket, receiveBuffer, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &connectedSocket, &length) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nrecvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        printf("\nServer Says : ");
        printf("\n\nI am from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(connectedSocket.sin_addr), ntohs(connectedSocket.sin_port));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you send the broadcast, start a timer and let it run for like 5-30 seconds.  During that time frame, process any replies you receive.  When the timer elapses, stop processing any more replies, just discard them if you happen to receive them.

No, a UDP socket cannot provide you with multiple datagrams at one time, you must read them individually.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is basically query all machines on the local network (running the server). Since I can only receive 1 message at a time, what do you think about checking if it is a new ip address and if so, increment counter (originally 5 lets say) to do 5? more broadcasts

Comment: I don't see a need to use a counter or multiple broadcasts at all. Send one broadcast. If you see a new IP, add it to your list and move on. Give yourself time to receive the replies, they may not be instantaneous. Just because YOU cannot receive more than one message at a time does not mean the SOCKET cannot. It has an internal receive buffer for a reason. As long as you are reading fast enough that the buffer does not fill up, you won't lose replies.

Comment: Just put the above if (recvfrom..) block in an infinite for loop to test and I did get all of the replies! Thanks a lot for your help and information about the buffer.